# Laravel homestead not working

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I'm trying to setup Homestead but it's not working. I've followed the documentation on https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead and watch the videos on laracast. But still can't figure out why it's not working. When I go to test.app:8000 the following message shows up:

> No input file specified.

Also when I changed paths in my homestead.yaml file I exec "vagrant provision".

This is how my homestead.yaml file looks like (in Homestead/Homestead.yaml):

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/documents/vagrant/sites
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: test.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/test

databases:
    - homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

The path of my folders: "~/documents/vagrant/sites" does exist because I can cd into it. I also added test.app to my etc/hosts file (see screenshot). 
[image]

What am I doing wrong... Trying to setup homestead for hours now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your /etc/hosts replace `127.0.0.1 test.app` with `192.168.10.10 test.app`.

Replace

```
sites:
- map: test.app
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/test
```

with

```
sites:
- map: test.app
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/test/public
```

Then run `vagrant provision`.

Comment: In your browser have you tried test.app? No test.app:8000

Comment: Yes, but still telling me: "No input file specified."

Comment: @jamie Try to `ssh` to Vagrant machine and after login run `cd Code/test/public`. Is it correct path? When you run `ls` do you see `index.php` in this directory?

Comment: it says no such file or directory. when i use cd  to get into the path. what should do now?? @MarcinNabiałek

Answer (score 0):

Create `index.php` in your test directory or if you are using laravel change your code to this

```
 sites:
        - map: test.app
          to: /home/vagrant/Code/test/public
```

Maybe this topic help you to understand the problem http://laravel.io/forum/06-04-2014-no-input-file-specified-using-homestead

Comment: Thanks working now. Is there a way how I can remove :8000 at the end? So I can just type test.app?